# Convert bignit to date (month name)

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, presto, bigint

I need to convert a field to date.

Currently the field is an integer for month (1, 2, 3....) that I want to convert to show as "January, February, March...."

How do I write the SQL (Presto) so that it converts from bigint to date?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select date_format(str_to_date('2000-' || 1 || '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), '%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no fiddle for Presto so I haven't tested this, but see if this does the trick

```
select date_format(date_add(month, your_integer_month, '2020-12-31'),'%M')
```